# How to add OpenCV files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am working on a project related to Image Processing and I have to use OpenCV in it. 
I am new to it and don't know how to add the OpenCV files in Visual Studio?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Extract the OpenCV install in any directory you want.
2. Copy the path of the directory where you extracted the OpenCV and add it to your System PATH.
3. Restart your computer to allow it to recognize new environment variables.
4. Open the properties of the project in Visual Studio and select VC++ Directories
5. Select ***Include Directories*** and select the path where OpenCV was extracted and add ***\build\include***.
6. Now Select ***Library Directories*** and select ***\build(processor_type)\vc12\lib***.

   > processor_type can be x86 or x64.
7. Now select ***Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies*** and add all the files there. Name of the files can be found [here](https://marcomuraresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/install-opencv-visual-studio/).
8. Compile the project and start using the OpenCV in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

among many methods i've tried this link is so simple and clear ( few steps 4-5), it works fine for me, visual studio 2022 & opencv4.6.0 [here](https://subwaymatch.medium.com/opencv-410-with-vs-2019-3d0bc0c81d96)

- download the version you want (.exe file) [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases)
- let's assume that you’ve extracted the contents to c:\
- Add opencv’s bin directory (C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin) to path
- Set platform target to x64 — Pre-built binaries are built for x64 Windows platforms.
- Add to Include Directories  : Tell the compiler how the OpenCV library looks. This is done by providing a path to the header files
- Add to Library Directories : Tell the linker where it can find the lib files for different modules.
- Add Additional Dependencies : List .lib files for different modules. Note that we’re only going to list a single all-in-one file named opencv_world.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33474920)

Comment: thanks for the advice, i've modified my answer :)